# Create a file in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have more than 40 documents which contain many files that I need to upload it to SharePoint libraries. How can I proceed to do it, should I create the document one by one or there is a way to drag and drop the documents.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the documents in one go using multiple upload.
It will work in IE.

You can check [this](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/upload-documents-into-folders-with-sharepoint-2010.html) link for further explanation.

Comment: it dosent work. and I have more than 100 folders and documents. there is a way to upload it to SharePoint2013 directely from dropbox or from my hard disk.

Comment: what issue are you facing?

Comment: it can upload only the documents and i should create the folders before

Answer (score 1):

You can drag and drop documents in IE. Make sure you drop them in the box that says "Drop Here". If you want to upload folders, you should open your document center in explorer view and then drag and drop away.

One caveat with drag'n'drop - you will have to check everything in.

Comment: I tried it and it says: sorry ... you could not upload folders and documents

Comment: Did you try adding multiple documents and/or folders? Try just one and see if that works...

Comment: You cannot drag folders directly into the browser

Comment: Yes your right ,first i need to open it with exploror

Comment: Make sure you check your documents in afterwards (if you have that feature turned on!) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found it in this video :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2HufMN9DgY
what I need it's to open with exploror and do the drag and drop .thank you all for your help

Comment: great go ahead,,